# How to determine the outcome of queries for constraint logic programming

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I am doing some revision for constraint logic programming and wanted to know how I can read the following queries in order to predicate their results correctly.

Basically there is a question which asks whether or not the answer provided by the following query is correct or not.

So this is the question

```
Consider the following queries and answers. Some answers coincide
with what SWI-Prolog would infer whereas others are erroneous.
Indicate which answers are genuine and which ones are fake (no
explanation is required).

(i) ?- [X, Y, Z] ins 0 .. 4, X #= Y + 1.
X in 1..4, Y in 0..3, Z in 0..4.

(ii) ?- [X, Y, Z] ins 0 .. 4, X #= Y + Z.
X in 0..4, Y in 0..2, Z in 0..2.

(iii) ?- [X, Y, Z] ins 0 .. 4, X #= Z - Y.
X in 0..4, Y in 0..4, Z in 0..4.

(iv) ?- [X, Y, Z] ins 0 .. 4, X #= Y * Y, Z #= -Y.
Y = 0, Z = 0.
```

My question is what is the best way to read the query in order to determine whether the answer is correct or not.

Comment: These are exam questions?? I would get an F anytime ...

Comment: @false Yeah these were exam question in past papers, I am trying to workout how to determine the answer based on the query.

Comment: There are computers for this, [not everywhere, though](http://dilbert.com/strip/1996-02-20).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several steps:

1. Is the shown answer a **syntactically valid** Prolog goal? If not, then the answer is definitely fake, because the actual toplevel only emits syntactically valid residual goals.
2. Moving on: Are there any solutions of the original query that are **precluded** by the shown residual goals? If yes (= *incompleteness*), then the answer is fake, because the actual toplevel only emits residual goals that are **semantically equivalent** to the original query.
3. Conversely, do the residual goals admit a solution that the initial query does not? If yes (= *overly general*), then the answer is fake. Exercise: Why?

In your case, the shown answer *is* a syntactically valid conjunction, so it is definitely a candidate for a correct solution. However, the answer admits solutions (exercise: which?) that the original query does not, and so the answer is **not correct**.

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it out and let me know what you think and what you think the best solution is to work out whether a question is fake or not

Comment: Please make a further edit where you answer, to the best of your ability, *each* of the 3 points I explained for all these tasks.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by points 2 and 3, but the code is syntactically valid and the information provided in the question is all the information I was given

Comment: Good, then try out the variants to get a feeling for the task. For example, consider just the first task. To find the concrete solutions of the original query, use for example: `?- [X, Y, Z] ins 0 .. 4, X #= Y + 1, label([X,Y,Z]).` this will show you all integers `X`, `Y` and `Z` that satisfy the constraints. And then contrast this with the residual goal they gave you:  `?- X in 1..4, Y in 0..3, Z in 0..4, label([X,Y,Z]).`. Again, you see concrete integers. Now, is the set of solutions the same for both variants? If they differ, they are *not* equivalent!  Practice a bit and think about it!